# Get a success message on same page after form submit / PHP AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I'm trying to config a contact form based on php/ajax to a website, but I can't manage to add a "success" message after the form is submitted. I receive the email correctly if I keep the "action" parameter to the php file inside form tag, but the page gets redirected to the blank php page. However, if I remove the link, the email is not sent.

I've tried in the past hours many of the suggestions I found online, but I can't manage to make it work properly. Any guesses?

Thanks

**HTML**

```
    <form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="simple-email-form-v1/form-to-email.php">

        <div class="control-group">
            <label>Your Name</label>
            <input class="fullname" type="text" name="fullname" />
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input class="email" type="text" name="email" />
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label>Phone (optional)</label>
            <input class="phone" type="text" name="phone" />
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea class="message" name="message"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div id="errors"></div>

        <div class="control-group no-margin">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
   <?php
/*
Configuration 
You are to edit these configuration values. Not all of them need to be edited.
However, the first few obviously need to be edited.
EMAIL_RECIPIENTS - your email address where you want to get the form submission.

*/

$email_recipients = "abcde@gmail.com";//<<=== enter your email address here
//$email_recipients =  "mymanager@gmail.com,his.manager@yahoo.com"; <<=== more than one recipients like this


$visitors_email_field = 'email';//The name of the field where your user enters their email address
                                        //This is handy when you want to reply to your users via email
                                        //The script will set the reply-to header of the email to this email
                                        //Leave blank if there is no email field in your form
$email_subject = "New Form submission";

$enable_auto_response = true;//Make this false if you donot want auto-response.

//Update the following auto-response to the user
$auto_response_subj = "Thanks for contacting us";
$auto_response ="
Hi

Thanks for contacting us. We will get back to you soon!

Regards
Your website
";

$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];


/*
This is the PHP back-end script that processes the form submission.
It first validates the input and then emails the form submission.
The variable $_POST contains the form submission data.
*/
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // note that our submit button's name is 'submit' 
    // We are checking whether submit button is pressed
    // This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!".print_r($_POST,true);
    exit;
}

require_once "includes/formvalidator.php";
//Setup Validations
$validator = new FormValidator();
$validator->addValidation("fullname","req","Please fill in Name");
$validator->addValidation("email","req","Please fill in Email");
//Now, validate the form
if(false == $validator->ValidateForm())
{
    echo "<B>Validation Errors:</B>";

    $error_hash = $validator->GetErrors();
    foreach($error_hash as $inpname => $inp_err)
    {
        echo "<p>$inpname : $inp_err</p>\n";
    }
    exit;
}

$visitor_email='';
if(!empty($visitors_email_field))
{
    $visitor_email = $_POST[$visitors_email_field];
}

if(empty($email_from))
{
    $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $email_from ="forms@$host";
}

$fieldtable = '';
foreach ($_POST as $field => $value)
{
    if($field == 'submit')
    {
        continue;
    }
    if(is_array($value))
    {
        $value = implode(", ", $value);
    }
    $fieldtable .= "$field: $value\n";
}

$extra_info = "User's IP Address: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";

$email_body = "You have received a new form submission. Details below:\n$fieldtable\n $extra_info";

$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
@mail(/*to*/$email_recipients, $email_subject, $email_body,$headers);

//Now send an auto-response to the user who submitted the form
if($enable_auto_response == true && !empty($visitor_email))
{
    $headers = `enter code here`"From: $email_from \r\n";
    @mail(/*to*/$visitor_email, $auto_response_subj, $auto_response,$headers);
}

//done. 

if(mail($email_recipients, $_POST["email"], $_POST["message"], $headers)) {
$message = "Success!";
} else {
$message = "Erro!";
}


?>
```

**JS**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#contact-form").validate({
        rules: {
            fullname: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 8000
            }
        },

        messages: { // custom messages
            fullname: {
                required: "Por favor, insira seu nome"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Por favor, insira seu email"
            },
            message: {
                required: "Por favor, insira sua mensagem",
                maxlength: jQuery.format("The maxlength for message is {0} !")
            },
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $form = $(form);
            $container = $form.parent();
            w = $form.outerWidth();
            h = $form.outerHeight();
            $form.hide();

            $('#msg_submitting', $container).width(w).height(h).fadeIn(1000);            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                       $("#mail-status").html(data);
        },
        error:function (){}
        });

            return false;

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: you're inserting the entire html in #mail-status   $("#mail-status").html(data);..... scrap the data that needs to be seen in #mail-status

Comment: am i guessing it right? .... AJAX will always return to the same page unless redirected manually ..

Answer (score 0):

Where is the "mail-status" id in html? You can replace "mail-status" with "errors".

The issue is there is no "mail-status" id in a page, so it is not displaying response on that div.

Define "mail-status" on html or just replace "mail-status" with "errors", as  your html contains .

Comment: I have just changed the "errors" div to "mail-status" id, but nothing has changed. Still redirecting to blank php page when I click on submit.

Comment: Simple. change the type of submit button to "button" from "submit"

Comment: <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
and use jquery to submit data. better to use ajax for it

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<div id="errors"></div>` outside the form element. When you are hiding the form the  `<div id="errors"></div>` also gets hidden hence you cannot see anything.

```
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="header.php">

      <div class="control-group">
          <label>Your Name</label>
          <input class="fullname" type="text" name="fullname" />
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input class="email" type="text" name="email" />
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
          <label>Phone (optional)</label>
          <input class="phone" type="text" name="phone" />
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
          <label>Message</label>
          <textarea class="message" name="message"></textarea>
      </div>


      <div class="control-group no-margin">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
      </div>

  </form>
  <div id="errors"></div>
```

Also in the php file you need to `echo $message;` so that it should be available in the ajax data param.

```
if(mail($email_recipients, $_POST["email"], $_POST["message"], $headers)) {
    $message = "Success!";
} else {
    $message = "Erro!";
}
echo $message;
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but now even though I'm not getting the blank php page, the form isn't sending the mail

Comment: Then there must be some problem in the PHP file. Please note that you cannot send mail from your local machine using the mail() function it will only work on the live server.

Answer (score 0):

First, add this element to the html :

```
<div id="mail-status"></div>
```

Then add `preventDefault()` to the js to prevent the form from submitting :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#contact-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // added preventDefault()
    }).validate({
        rules: {
            fullname: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 8000
            }
        },

        messages: { // custom messages
            fullname: {
                required: "Por favor, insira seu nome"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Por favor, insira seu email"
            },
            message: {
                required: "Por favor, insira sua mensagem",
                maxlength: jQuery.format("The maxlength for message is {0} !")
            },
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $form = $(form);
            $container = $form.parent();
            w = $form.outerWidth();
            h = $form.outerHeight();

            $('#msg_submitting', $container).width(w).height(h).fadeIn(1000);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#mail-status").html(data);
                },
                error: function () {}
            });
            $form.hide(); // moved below ajax call

            return false;

        }

    });

});

</script>
```

Then don't forget to add `echo` statement to the php :

```
if(mail($email_recipients, $_POST["email"], $_POST["message"], $headers)) {
    $message = "Success!";
} else {
    $message = "Erro!";
}

echo $message;
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but now even though I'm not getting the blank php page, the form isn't sending the mail

Comment: by removing this line  `e.preventDefault(); // added preventDefault()` the mail arrives, but it redirects to the php page

Comment: Hi @PedroF , I've updated the code, moving `$form.hide();` below the ajax call, could you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might help you:

```
<div id="mail-status"></div>
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="simple-email-form-v1/form-to-email.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the way you handle the submit is causing the page to redirect?

Change your button type `submit` to a `button`. See below,

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
```

Then, target the button click for the form submission, like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#submit').click(function(){
         //do you logic here
     });
});
```

When changing the button type to be a `button`, you don't need to worry about `preventDefault()` for submission, because submission only happens through through Ajax / JS.

Hope this helps.

Cheers